# Find and read all checked checkboxes and push their names in an array

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkBoxes on my page and using javascript I want to find all **checked boxes** and push their repective names in an array as follows:

```
    var Names = new Array();
 $.each($(':checked'), function (key, value) {
 Name.push($(value).attr("name"));
 });
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just select by pseudoelement: `:checked`. You must select all `<input type="checkbox">` elements that are checked:

```
var Names = new Array();
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function (key, value) {
    Name.push($(value).attr("name"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A more "functional" way:

```
var names = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.name;
}).get();
```

Or maybe it is better to not use the `:checked` pseudo selector so that jQuery can make better use of the browser functions:

```
var names = $('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function() {
    if(this.selected) {
        return this.name;
    }
    return null;
}).get();
```

**Reference:** [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Names = new Array();
 $(':checkbox:checked').each( function (key, value) {
     Name.push($(value).attr("name"));
 });
```

or even easier:

```
var Names = new Array();
$(':checkbox:checked').each( function () {
    Name.push( $( this ).attr( "name" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Names = new Array();
 $.each($('input:checked'), function (key, value) {
 Names.push($(value).attr("name"));
 });
```

You are using Name, and Names  --  2 different uh..names

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason for the jQuery map function.

```
var Names = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function (value) {
     return value.name;
 });
```

Comment: You would also need `.get()`.